# Yang Mills gradient/heat flow on 4-torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics

The classic Donaldson-Kronheimer book (Geometry of 4-manifolds) uses the Yang Mills gradient flow (sometimes called heat flow) on $M$ all over the place,

$\frac{d A}{dt} = -\frac{\delta YM(A)}{\delta A}$

where $YM(A)$ is the Yang Mills 'action' the integral of the curvature square,

$YM(A) = \int d^4x Tr F_{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu} > 0$

The setting is quite general, either $M$ is a general 4-manifold or Kahler manifold and so all theorems, existence, uniqueness, etc, are quite general.

I'm wondering if there are further results somewhere for the specific case of $M = T^4$ the 4-torus. For example, is it known how the long time asymptotics look like in this case? Theorems about possible blow-ups? I'd think asymptotically the gradient flow drives the connection towards a critical point but is it known how it is approached, exponentially or polynomially in $t$?

Actually for $M=T^4$ I suspect $t^2 YM(A(t))$ goes to a constant for $t\to\infty$ as long as the initial condition for the flow is in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of the absolute minimum of $YM(A)$ but I can't prove it. What is certainly true is that $YM(A(t))$ is a decreasing function of $t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Donaldson and Kronheimer wrote their book by 1990. There were some further developments about long time behaviour of Yang-Mills flow on four manifolds by, among others, Struwe and collaborators. You may try starting with [Schlatter's dissertation](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1443269).

Crawling through MathSciNet reference links may get you "somewhere", but it is my impression that higher dimensional Yang-Mills heat flow is still somewhat of an open problem. Is there any reason why you expect $\mathbb{T}^4$ would be better behaved than, say, the unit ball?

Comment: Thanks, the Schlatter reference was really useful!

The reason I'm asking about $T^4$ is that this is the case I can study numerically. When I numerically solve the gradient flow it seems to have the property that $t^2 YM(A(t))$ goes to a constant, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: How about starting first in $\mathbb{T}^3$ or $\mathbb{T}^2$ (just to test out your numerical algorithm). Rade showed http://www.reference-global.com/doi/abs/10.1515/crll.1992.431.123 polynomial rates of convergence for global existence. 

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks for the reference, unfortunately our university doesn't appear to have digital subscription so can't access the article. Does anyone have a digital copy?

Comment: @Daniel: strangely enough, *no-one* I know has access to the digital copy. (And in a moment of lack of wisdom, I tossed out my paper copy after seeing that the article is "available on-line", only to find out it was, in fact, not the case for me.) This is one of those cases you'll just have to buckle down and go photocopy it from a paper copy of the journal. 

Comment: @Daniel: ah, I just found out the "proper" way of accessing the digital copy. Try this link: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/toc/?PPN=PPN243919689  If your institution has a subscription, you should be able to find the paper under "Band 431". Else you can send me an e-mail. 

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just take a look at the following paper:

http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1103/1103.0845v1.pdf

(In particular it should exponential convergence.) Should there still be question, you might post them!

Comment: That paper is only dealing with the flow on Riemann surfaces.